# The three missing titles of Shofet

Tags: tanach, shoftim--book-of

The era commonly known as the period of the *Shoftim*, Judges of the Jewish nation, spanned from the leadership of Osniel Ben K'naz through *Shimshon Hagibor*.

Prior to these judges, The Seder olam also notes that Yehoshuah Bin Nun also [served as a Shofet for 28 years](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93490/at-what-stage-of-joshuas-leadership-did-he-become-judge).

At the end of this period, Shmuel Hanavi, and later his 2 sons Yoel and Aviyah also served as Shoftim.

This ended the Shoftim era, and the era of Melachim, kings, began with the appointment of Shaul as the first king.

Question: Among these leaders who led the Bnai Yisrael between Osniel Ben K'naz through Shmuel and his sons all are titled in the psukim as Judges, except for 3 of them:

1- Ehud Ben Gera - See Shoftim 3:15  " **וַיָּקֶם ה' לָהֶם מוֹשִׁיעַ**, אֶת אֵהוּד בֶּן גֵּרָא בֶּן הַיְמִינִי, ". Ehud was called a "Helper" or "savior" rather than a *Shofet*.

2- Gidon ben Yoash - See Shoftim 6:14  "וַיִּפֶן אֵלָיו ה', וַיֹּאמֶר 'לֵךְ בְּכֹחֲךָ זֶה **וְהוֹשַׁעְתָּ אֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל** מִכַּף מִדְיָן, הֲלֹא שְׁלַחְתִּיךָ" - Gedon was also appointed as a "helper" / "savior"rather than as a Shofet.

3- Shamgar ben Anas - "וְאַחֲרָיו הָיָה שַׁמְגַּר בֶּן-עֲנָת, וַיַּךְ אֶת-פְּלִשְׁתִּים שֵׁשׁ-מֵאוֹת אִישׁ בְּמַלְמַד הַבָּקָר; **וַיּוֹשַׁע גַּם-הוּא אֶת-יִשְׂרָאֵל**" - a "Helper" or "savior" of Yisarel rather than a *Shofet*.

Why the difference between these 3 and the rest?

Comment: Shamgar isn't called a shofet either.

Comment: @Heshy Thank you very much. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Ehud the Malbim 3/15 writes that he only led them against their enemies, but did not lead them in "Das" Torah law.

Comment: Thank you. Anything about Gidon?

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore - Gidoen is called קלי עולם in the Gemorah Rosh Hashana 25b, but so were Shimshon and Yiftach. Nothing yet.